# jQuery Mobile: Spinner stuck (ui-loader) on deployed source

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Running my website from VS2015, every page loads as expected.
However, deploying the source to a test server (IIS) the page spinner is stuck.

It seems that it's the display property on .ui-loading .ui-loader that makes the spinner persist. Though I can't find any good reason why this only happens on the deployed version, not while running from VS.

The issue is found both in Chrome and IE10.

[image: Spinner]
[image]

I am using jQuery Mobile 1.4.5.

Not quite sure where to investage further on this issue.

My current workaround is to override the display property

```
<style>
.ui-loading .ui-loader{
  display: none;
}
  </style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting all files from the IIS server, and uploading a fresh deployment fixed the issue.